# pandas.DataFrame: .hist() vs .plot.hist() methods

Tags: python, pandas

On `pandas.DataFrame` in 0.19 there are two hist methods:

[DataFrame.hist](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html)

[DataFrame.plot.hist](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html)

At first I thought they were the same, but actually they take different arguments. Is one going to be deprecated in a future release, is there a different use case for each, or what's the story?

Comment: I believe there is something else going on under the covers. For my data, these two calls considerably different times: df.plot.hist is more than 10 times slower.

Comment: To further confuse people, there is even a third option: `pandas.DataFrame.plot(kind="hist")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer for you. One thing I noticed is that `DataFrame.hist` returns a list of axes objects and `DataFrame.plot.hist` returns only one. For example:

```
# Making up data
df = pd.DataFrame({'value1': np.random.normal(1, 1, 99),
                   'value2': [-1]*33 + [0]*33 + [1]*33})

df.hist()
```

[image]

```
df.plot.hist()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the docs, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html, it looks like `plot.hist` is a function that takes a few histogram specific options but then passes on all other keyword args to `plot()`, while hist takes a large number of keyword args directly.  I would guess that this is primarily to create a simpler, more consistent API, i.e. rather than having 15 different functions that each take a large number of `kwargs`, just focus on the specialized args while the rest are consistent with `plot()`

cf:

> New in version 0.17.0: Each plot kind has a corresponding method on
>   the DataFrame.plot accessor: df.plot(kind='line') is equivalent to
>   df.plot.line()

In addition, the plot* functions return `axes`, which could be useful for chaining and other things.

Comment: actually the old style functions return the axes as well

Comment: True, but if there is more than one column it returns an array of axes instead (as pointed out in another answer), so it probably would not be as convenient for chaining.

Comment: I don't know if there is a consistent preference on this, but I did find this request (still open, but > 4 years old) that suggests deprecating df.hist in favor of df.plot.hist.  In my purely subjective opinion, df.plot.hist seems like a more consistent API.